# Replace ssl certificate in bundle

Tags: nginx, ssl-certificate

I'm not really used to administration stuff so please bear with me.

Recently, the server's certificate from RapidSSL expired and we renewed an received a new one. TO replace the cert, I opened up bundle.crt with vim, removed the top entry and inserted the new one. [running nginx here]

```
Testing nginx configuration: nginx: [emerg] SSL_CTX_use_PrivateKey_file("/data/gits/foo/etc/ssl/PAC.key") failed (SSL: error:0B080074:x509 certificate routines:X509_check_private_key:key values mismatch)
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed
```

Hmm any idea?

Answer (score 1):

This will happen when the server certificate and the bundle have been concatenated in the wrong order, because nginx has tried to use the private key with the bundle’s first certificate instead of the server certificate.

Please find the correct order,

```
cat yourdomain_com.crt PositiveSSLCA2.crt AddTrustExternalCARoot.crt > yourdomain.com.pem
```

See also the Nginx docs on [HTTPS](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/configuring_https_servers.html)